# Install i3gaps on Debian (Raspberry Pi OS)

Tags: debian, raspbian, i3

I decided to install i3WM on my Raspberry Pi 400 with Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 11 bullseye aarch64). The only missing part is i3gaps/i3-gaps, but I can't install it with "sudo apt install". Is there any other way to install it?

Comment: `i3-gaps` hast to be compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian bookworm's `i3-wm` package already contains i3gaps. But: Debian bullseye's `i3-wm` doesn't.

So, if you're reading this at a time where the current version of Raspberry Pi OS is based on debian 12 (bookworm) or later already, you don't have to do anything but `sudo apt install i3wm`. Updating your raspberry Pi OS isn't hard, so try that.

The rest of us will have to build the `i3-wm` package ourselves with all the debian modifications to it. (you could also manually build parts of it, but manually building is typically hard for beginners, error-prone.)

No matter how you do it, you'll need roughly 1 GB of free space, at least, on your system disk.

1. Get the .dsc file link from the debian that describes the package. It's on the right right hand side of https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/i3-wm under "Download Source package"
2. On your RPi, make a new directory (`mkdir package`), change into it `cd package`).
3. Install the tools necessary to build debian packages automatically: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y build-essential fakeroot devscripts`
4. run `dget THE_LINK_YOU_JUST_COPIED` (obviously, replacing `THE_LINK_YOU_JUST_COPIED` with the link to the .dsc file)
5. Get all the things you need to build that package: `sudo mk-build-deps -i *.dsc`
6. Change into the directory with the source code, which `dget` got in step 4.: `cd i3-wm-*/`
7. Let the tools do the automatic build: `debuild -b -uc -us`
8. Go up one directory (`cd ..`) and finally
9. Install the new package that has been built for you from this directory: `sudo apt-get install -y ./i3_*.deb ./i3-wm_*.deb`

If all worked out: You can now also clean up things you no longer need; `sudo apt-get remove build-essential fakeroot devscripts i3-wm-build-deps; sudo apt-get autoremove`